# Error: "An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator" for Linq with from

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am getting the following error when I am write the following Linq - can somebody please suggest me to write the same without getting the error.
My Linq is as follows:

```
                myOrphanList =
                        (
                            from v in allViolations
                            from r in allInspectionResults
                            from i in allItems
                            where
                                r.InspectionResultId == i.InspectionResultId &&
                                i.InspectionItemId == v.InspectionItemId
                            select new OrphanViolationsReport
                            {
                                ViolationId = v.ViolationId,
                                ViolationNumber = v.ViolationNumber,
                                ViolationDate = v.ViolationDate,
                                ViolationType = v.ViolationType.ViolationTypeCode,
                                ItemYear = i.ItemYear,
                                ItemMakeManufacturer = i.ItemMakeManufacturer,
                                ItemModel = i.ItemModel,
                                VIN = i.VIN,
                                PIN = i.PIN,
                                InspectionResultId = r.InspectionResultId,
                                InspectionResultNumber = r.InspectionRequestNumber,
                                DealerDmvNumber = r.DealerDmvNumber,
                                InspectedCompanyName = (from a in contacts where a.ContactId == r.InspectedCompanyDataId select a.FirstName)?.FirstOrDefault()
                            }
                        ).ToList();
```

At the line "InspectedCompanyName = (from a in contacts where a.ContactId == r.InspectedCompanyDataId select a.FirstName)?.FirstOrDefault()"
I am getting following error - how can I get rid of it - thank you

```
An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator
```

Any help please

Comment: Just remove `?.`, query before will never return `null`. It will return empty collection if there are no items which satisfies condition.

Comment: Also most probably you want to use `?.` after `FirstOrDefault` to access the properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a weird rule of LINQ. The problem is in the expression:

```
InspectedCompanyName = (from a in contacts where a.ContactId == r.InspectedCompanyDataId select a.FirstName)?.FirstOrDefault()
```

which is inside your select. `?.` is not allowed.

Thankfully, `?:` (the ternary operator/inline conditional) is allowed, so this can be rewritten. For convenience you need a let:

```
myOrphanList =
(
    from v in allViolations
    from r in allInspectionResults
    from i in allItems
    where
        r.InspectionResultId == i.InspectionResultId &&
        i.InspectionItemId == v.InspectionItemId
    let firstName = from a in contacts // Pop your sub-query in a variable here
                    where a.ContactId == r.InspectedCompanyDataId 
                    select a.FirstName
    select new OrphanViolationsReport
    {
        ViolationId = v.ViolationId,
        ViolationNumber = v.ViolationNumber,
        ViolationDate = v.ViolationDate,
        ViolationType = v.ViolationType.ViolationTypeCode,
        ItemYear = i.ItemYear,
        ItemMakeManufacturer = i.ItemMakeManufacturer,
        ItemModel = i.ItemModel,
        VIN = i.VIN,
        PIN = i.PIN,
        InspectionResultId = r.InspectionResultId,
        InspectionResultNumber = r.InspectionRequestNumber,
        DealerDmvNumber = r.DealerDmvNumber,
        // USe ternary operator here
        InspectedCompanyName = firstName == null ? null : firstName
    }
).ToList();
```

This is too complex for me to test compile, but that's basically the idea.

That said, as @SalahAkbari points out, the logic here is very strange. A select query (the one I've put into `firstName`) will never return `null`, it will return an empty collection, so what's the point?